# Email address validation in C# MVC 4 application: with or without using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, email-validation

I have an MVC 4 web application and I need to enter and validate some email addresses, without sending an email to the user's email address.

Currently I am using basic regex email validation with this pattern:

```
[RegularExpression(@"\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z",
        ErrorMessage = "Please enter correct email address")]
```

Although this is validating email addresses, it passes 1@1.1 as a valid email address. For the moment I have a validation that requires symbols @ symbols . symbols where the symbols can be numeric/alphabetic and ._- .

I need more standard email validation for my MVC 4 application. How do I do that?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You need a regular expression for this. Look [here](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-email-address-with-regular-expression/). If you are using .net Framework4.5 then you can also use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.EmailAddressAttribute%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true). As it is built in .net Framework 4.5. 
Example

```
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: I have used [DataType(DataType.EmailAdress)] attribute and string length attribute, but as I see I have forgotten to put the [EmailAdress] attribute.The validation is good now. Thank you

Comment: this will validate @ only

Answer (score 24):

Expanding on [Ehsan's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20400565/961113)....

If you are using .Net framework 4.5 then you can have a simple method to verify email address using [`EmailAddressAttribute` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.emailaddressattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) in code.

```
private static bool IsValidEmailAddress(string emailAddress)
{
    return new System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
                        .EmailAddressAttribute()
                        .IsValid(emailAddress);
}
```

If you are considering REGEX to verify email address then read:

[I Knew How To Validate An Email Address Until I Read The RFC](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/) By [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/about/)

Comment: Strangely, a trailing period at the end of the email passes validation.

Comment: @TTT, did you find a way to validate trailing period case?

Comment: @user2866746 - it's because a trailing period is valid for the domain name, so I just left it. It should resolve just fine.

Comment: But in my case, I'm seeing the email not getting sent to the email address which contain a trailing period.

Comment: One of the end user entered (Eg: `abc@mailinator.com.`) which is correctly validate by the Model binder but the problem is, email can not be send to this address and it says, `A valid address is required.`

Answer (score 16):

Regex:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid e-mail adress")]
```

Or you can use just:

```
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: I would up using a combination of both.  Apparently a@a is a valid email, or at least it passes the EmailAddress attribute validation.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use the `EmailAttribute`?

```
[Email(ErrorMessage = "Bad email")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: where's the EmailAttribute defined?

Answer (score 1):

*Don't.*

Use a regex for a quick sanity check, something like `.@..`, but almost all langauges / frameworks have better methods for checking an e-mail address. Use that.

It is *possible* to validate an e-mail address with a regex, but it is a long regex. [*Very* long](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/02/regex-use-vs-regex-abuse.html).
And in the end you will be none the wiser. You'll only know that the *format* is valid, but you still don't know if it's an active e-mail address. The only way to find out, is by sending a confirmation e-mail.

Comment: The confirmation e-mail is the thing i cannot do. I need just to add some emails in a list for later function with a service reporting tool. Problem solved though so thx for the time ;]

Answer (score 0):

It is surprising the question of [validating an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/1497596) continually comes up on SO!

You can find one often-mentioned **practical solution** here: [How to Find or Validate an Email Address](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

**Excerpt:**

> The virtue of my regular expression above is that it matches 99% of
>   the email addresses in use today. All the email address it matches can
>   be handled by 99% of all email software out there. If you're looking
>   for a quick solution, you only need to read the next paragraph. If you
>   want to know all the trade-offs and get plenty of alternatives to
>   choose from, read on.

See [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201329/1497596) for a discussion of the merits of the article at the above link. In particular, the comment dated 2012-04-17 reads:

> To all the complainers: after 3 hours experimenting all the solutions
>   offered in this gigantic discussion, this is THE ONLY good java regex
>   solution I can find. None of the rfc5322 stuff works on java regex.

Comment: Should i again answer that i don't need basic validation and I was looking for a way to validate email in MVC4 application.As pointed out there is other way: with attribute that i forgot to put on.I have used the given example and yet the email validation with that regex expression was passing bad email formats for my case.